# Why infinimum of upper sum and supremum of lower sum will be the only point in between?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, upper-lower-bounds

Let’s say we have a function $f$, and let $L(f,P)$ denotes the lower sum of $f$ on any partition $P$ and $U(f,P)$ the upper sum of $f$ on $P$.
My book writes :
 If $$sup\{ L(f,P): \text{P is a any partition}\} = inf \{U(f,P) : \text{P is any partition}\}$$ Then they are the only number in between upper and lower sums of $f$ on any partition.

I really don’t know why they will be the only number in between. Can someone help me here?

Let’s say we have a set of partitions $$A = \{P_1, P_2, P_3 .... P_n\}$$ such that $P_2$ have more numbers of points than $P_1$, $P_3$ have more number of points than $P_2$ and so on. $P_n$ contains the largest number of points. Then by the Lemma we know $$ L(f, P_1)\leq L(f,P_2)\leq .... \leq L(f,P_n)$$ and $$ U(f,P_n) \leq U(f, P_{n-1} \leq ... U(f,P_1)$$ if $$L(f,P_n) = U(f, P_n)$$ then also we have so many points/numbers between any two upper and lower sum (of same partition). For example, let’s choose the partition $P_5$, for it we have $$ L(f,P_5) \leq L(f,P_6) ... \leq L(f,P_n) = U(f,P_n) \leq U(f,P_{n-1}) ... \leq U(f,P_5)$$ we got so many numbers between the upper and lower sum of $f$ at partition $P_5$.

Please explain what he meant.

Comment: Do you know what inf and sup mean?

Comment: @saulspatz supremum: the greatest member of a set.

Comment: Infinimum: lowest/smallest member of a set.

Comment: Not quite.  They're the greatest lower bound and the least upper bound.  They needn't be elements of the set.  I don't understand your difficulty though.  The infimum over the set of upper sums is less than or equal to any of the upper sums.  What does $U(f,P_5)$ have to do with this?   You seem to be looking at the wrong end.  You should be looking at the middle.

Comment: Note by the way that just number of points is not quite how refinement works. What happens is if you add a point *and include all the old points*, the upper sum can only go down and the lower sum can only go up. If you add two points and delete an old point, you may increase the upper sum, depending on where the three points in question were. In math language, the useful ordering on partitions is set containment, rather than number of elements.

Comment: (Cont.) To actually address your question, if the sup of the lower sums equals the inf of the upper sums, then their common value is the only number lying nonstrictly between the lower and upper sums of *all* partitions. Of course if you have a particular partition it will typically have a whole interval of numbers between its lower and upper sum.

Comment: @Ian Thank you, you are more clearer than the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$L(f,P_1) \leq L(f,P_2) ... \leq \sup L(f,P) \leq \inf U(f,P) \leq... U(f,P_2) \leq U(f,P_1),$$ no matter how the partitions are chosen.  Both $\sup L(f,P)$ and $\inf L(f,P)$ are greater than or equal to all the lower sums, and both are less than or equal to all the upper sums.  If it happens that $\sup L(f,P)=\inf L(f,P)$, then their common value is the only number with this property.  (Of course if they're not equal, then any number in between them also has the property.)

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but I still didn't get the idea "their common value is the only number between any lower and upper sum".

Comment: Yes, now I released that the book meant something else and I understood it differently. Your answer really helped me.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with upper or lower sums or partitions.

> **Obvious result**: If a non-empty set $A$ of real numbers is bounded above and another non-empty set $B$ of real numbers is bounded below with $\sup A=\inf B=c\text{ (say)} $ then $c$ is the unique number which lies between elements of $A$ and elements of $B$.

Well first of all there can't be two distinct such elements like $c, d$ with property mentioned above. If there were such numbers with $c<d$ then we have $$a\leq c<d\leq b$$ for all $a\in A, b\in B$. But this implies $\sup A\leq c<d\leq \inf B$ which is contrary to our hypotheses.

On the other hand $c$ possesses this property by definition of supremum and infimum.

Comment: You are helping me very much in my analysis, thanks :-).

Comment: @Knight: if it really helped I am more than happy and that serves my purpose here (reputation is anyway secondary agenda).

Comment: I really admire that virtue of yours,I think it is immoral to uncheck the above answer and mark this one because two days have passed.

Comment: @Knight: no worries man! Those points don't really matter. Not worth a penny in market.

Comment: yes, very true :-)